# Numero consecutivo entre dos valores

Tags: php, mysql

¿Existe alguna función en php para generar números consecutivos tipo rand(1,100); pero que sean consecutivos?

Necesito poder aportarle el numero de inicio y el numero final.

O quizás se puede hacer directamente en mysql... Explico lo que quiero hacer que lo mismo estoy Utilizando demasiados pasos.

Tengo una tabla de códigos ean-13 en mysql donde guardo los números fijos del ean y los variables los variables son dos campos en mysql el numero primer codigo que tengo y el ultimo. Las tablas son: Pais | Codigo | valorinicial | valorfinal que equivaldrían a 84 | 36562 | 00001 | 99999 Los dos primeros son fijos y los dos finales son el rango de códigos que tengo comprados.

Por otro lado tengo otra tabla donde asigno esos códigos ean a un articulo en concreto comprobando que no este ya asignado y asignando el primero que este libre.

La idea inicial era generar un array con todos los códigos que tengo comprados, Hacer un query para comprobar que no estén asignados a un articulo y asignárselos en un insert. Pero lo mismo lo puedo hacer todo en la misma consulta.

¿Se puede de un golpe? si no se puede ¿existe la función rand(1,100) para php pero siendo consecutivos?

He probado con esto:

```
        $CCodEan = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Configuraciones","`que` = 'Codigos' AND `1` = '".$_SESSION['Empresa_Pais']."' ");

        $CeanLibre = "SELECT min(3) + 1 as prox_ean_libre FROM (SELECT 0 AS 3 union all SELECT 3 FROM Direcciones&Codigos WHERE 3 >= '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[4]."' AND 3 <= '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[5]."' ) t1 WHERE not exists (select null FROM Direcciones&Codigos t2 WHERE t2.3 = t1.3 + 1 AND t2.3 >= '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[4]."' AND t2.3 <= '".$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[5]."' )"; //miramos de nuevo el ultimo codigo por si aca
        $REanLibre = mysqli_query($Conectar ,$CeanLibre); //pongo un resultado de la consulta

        $DEanLibre=mysqli_fetch_array($REanLibre); 
        $EanLibre = trim($DEanLibre["prox_ean_libre"]);

echo $EanLibre;
```

pero me da error.

En este caso `3` es el campo donde guardo los códigos ean para los artículos y `$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[4]` seria el primer codigo ean completo ( a falta del dígito de control) y `$CCodEan[2].$CCodEan[3].$CCodEan[5]` seria el ultimo codigo que tengo (también sin el dígito de control).

Mil gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: y no puedes obtener un max del pais/codigo ya asignados, verificar q el proximo es asignable, y usar ese? digo para no tener que andar buscando como loco numeros.

Comment: También lo había pensado pero ¿como se que he llegado al limite?

Comment: verificando que ese numero no haya sobrepasado el valor final para pais/codigo. no se php, y no parece que tu problema venga por el lenguaje en si, si no en la construccion del algoritmo. Si te sirve, lo pongo como respuesta.

Comment: Me has dado una idea @gbianchi estoy probando a ver si lo consigo

Comment: será [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.range.php) lo que estas buscando?

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta incluye varias preguntas en si misma. Te repondo en referencia a una funcion que te devuelva en un array todos los valores entre 2 numeros.

```
function resultado($numero_inicial, $numero_final){
    for ($i=$numero_inicial;$i<$numero_final;$i++){
        $numeros[] = $i;
    }
    return $numeros;
}
```

Como invocar a esta funcion?

```
resultado(10, 100);
resultado(1000, 50000);
```